# How to export IntelliJ IDEA project for compiling on another machine without IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I wrote a Java program using IntelliJ IDEA. Now I want to compile my source code on another machine which has no IntelliJ IDEA and only has javac. How can I export IntelliJ IDEA project as pure Java source code tarball so that I can compile my source code on that machine?

Comment: Write a maven/gradient build file; IntelliJ can understand it and you can then also compile with maven or grader alone

Comment: In case it helps the OP, the name of that build tool is "Gradle" :-)

Comment: See [What are the advantages of build scripts?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/288205/what-are-the-advantages-of-build-scripts)

Answer (score 1):

Ideally you should be using a build system such as [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/) or [Gradle](https://gradle.org). This will remove the burden of depending on IDE settings and is support by all Java IDEs

Now if you still insist on using an IDE only without a build system. The export feature in IntelliJ and Eclipse both will come handy for you